# Segmentation fault with MPI shared memory and quad precision

Tags: c, gcc, mpi, intel, shared-memory

A very simple C program using MPI shared memory crashes for me when quadruple precision (`__float128`) is used with GCC (but not with the Intel C compiler). The program allocates a shared real array one element long for every MPI process (allocation is done by the master process and then accessed by other processes). Each process writes into one of the elements and prints another element to standard output. When using standard built-in types `float` and `double` (or just single process), there are no problems at all. When using `__float128` (and more than one process), the highlighted line below results in segmentation fault for all processes.

```c
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int verbose = 0;

/* typedef float real; */
/* typedef double real; */
typedef __float128 real;

#define _(FUN, ARGS) \
{ \
    int status = FUN ARGS; \
    if (verbose) printf(#FUN " exit code: %d\n", status); \
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int nprocs, rank, assert = 0, disp = 1, master = 0, bytesize = sizeof(real);
    void* baseptr = NULL;
    real* arr;
    MPI_Win win;

    printf("Data type byte size: %d\n", bytesize);

    _(MPI_Init,      (&argc, &argv))
    _(MPI_Comm_size, (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs))
    _(MPI_Comm_rank, (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank))

    MPI_Aint totsize = rank == 0 ? bytesize * nprocs : 0;

    _(MPI_Win_allocate_shared, (totsize, disp, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &baseptr, &win))
    _(MPI_Win_shared_query,    (win, master, &totsize, &disp, &arr))
    _(MPI_Win_fence,           (assert, win))

    arr[rank] = rank + 1;  /*  <-- Segmentation fault here when using __float128 */

    _(MPI_Win_fence, (assert, win))

    printf("Element %d: %g\n", (rank + 1) % nprocs, (double)arr[(rank + 1) % nprocs]);

    _(MPI_Win_fence, (assert, win))
    _(MPI_Win_free,  (&win));
    _(MPI_Finalize,  ());

    return 0;
}
```

The program works in some configurations, but not in others. Here are those that I was able to check:

| Compiler | Open MPI 4.1.0 | Intel MPI (oneAPI 2021) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Intel oneAPI 2021 `mpiicc` | OK for all types | OK for all types |
| GCC 9.3 `mpicc` | FAILS with `__float128` | N/A |
| GCC 10.2 `mpicc` | FAILS with `__float128` | N/A |

I use openSUSE Tumbleweed 20210319.

On the first sight, this seems to be a problem in GCC. Or am I missing something in the code?

Comment: You're creating a window of reals, but your `disp` is 1? I would use `sizeof(real)`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I have to say that the purpose of `disp` is still unclear to me, even after reading the MPI 3.1 standard. For my use cases (= obtaining and using a pointer to the shared memory segment) it does not seem to matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is `MPI_Win_allocate_shared()` returns a memory area aligned on 8 bytes, but GCC assumes `arr` is aligned on 16 bytes and a crash can occur if `arr` is not aligned on 16 bytes.

You can work around this issue by manually realigning the data.

```
#define REALIGN(a, type) \
    ((a) + sizeof(type) - 1 & ~(sizeof(type) - 1))
```

and then

```
    MPI_Aint totsize = rank == 0 ? (bytesize * (nprocs+1)) : 0;
```

and finally

```
    arr = (real *)REALIGN((unsigned long)arr, real);
```

FWIW, on recent Intel processors, aligned and non aligned instructions run at the same speed when the data is aligned, and that is likely why the Intel compiler do not generate aligned instructions any more.

Comment: I think that the `(..., real)` in you second code block is some accidental leftover. But otherwise this works like a charm, thank you very much! Once the `(..., real)` is sorted, I will accept this.

Comment: BTW, now that I know what to look at: Intel compiler apparently aligns all allocations at 16 bytes by default, and `MPI_Win_allocate_shared` from Intel MPI returns blocks aligned at 4096 bytes regardless of size!